# Why is there no manifest.mf in the “dist/” directory and why is jar file not working?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I'm new to NetBeans and I cannot find the MANIFEST.MF that [this link](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) tells me there should be when I click "Clean and Build" in the IDE.

However, I only see a .jar file and a README.TXT. Anyone have any idea about this?

I am completely new to NetBeans, so simple terms would be much appreciated!

Also, when I run my project in the IDE, it creates and displays a jFrame but when I double click the jar file, nothing shows up. I have done setVisible() and I have set the default close operation, so that is not the problem. When I was searching for an answer, I found out that this could be because I did not specify my main class in my manifest. So this may be tied in with the top question so that is why I am combining these two questions.

Thanks in advance, guys!

I am using NetBeans 7.2 Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the manifest.mf file is not located in the "dist/" directory but in the root directory of the project. I am able to locate it now. However, I am still unable to figure out why the jar was not working. It is working now. Maybe my machine was just acting up or maybe I was using up too much RAM so my computer did not want to run another program? Anyway, everything is solved now. Thanks for everyone to answered!

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `.jar` file using WinRar and then check inside the META-INF folder for MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: I don't have WinRar but I got it to work somehow. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Why WinRar? The JAR utility is present in the JDK and is entirely adequate for any task involving .jar files.